# Calculate message hash for eth_signTypedData

Tags: javascript, php, ethereum, metamask

I am trying to understand eth_signTypedMessage with Metamask and a little toy example.

Code in Browser (using Metamask and Chrome):

```
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_signTypedData', params: [
  [
    {
      type: 'string',
      name: 'testname',
      value: '1234567890'
    }
  ],
  publicAddress
] }).then((signedData) => {
    SendSignedDataToBackend(signedData);
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the message hash of the typed data, but I can't really get it straight with [the standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712):

Backend php code (using the old php ECRecover):

```
$typeHash     = Keccak::hash('(string testname)',256); // Also no success without the brackets
$encodeData   = keccak::hash("1234567890",256);
$typedMsgHash = keccak::hash(hex2bin($typeHash.$encodeData),256);

$ecRecover    = new EcRecover();
$address      = $ecRecover->personalEcRecover($typedMsgHash,$signedData);
```

This results in the wrong public address. Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

After going through the code of Metamask, it seems that Metamask signs the plain message:

```
sign(message)
```

and not as I expected

```
sign(keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + len(message) + message)))
```

This does not seem to follow EIP-712, but maybe I misunderstood it. Removing the extra hash calculation of "\x19Ethereum ..." on the server solved the problem. $typeHash calculation is without the brackets in the code of my question. Also need to add an extra "0x" in my code:

```
$typedMsgHash = '0x'.keccak::hash(hex2bin($typeHash.$encodeData),256);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be too late, landed here 2 years laters and still no solution, I had to write a package to solve this.
[sleepfinance/eip712](https://packagist.org/packages/sleepfinance/eip712)

Format your data according to [the JSON schema specified by EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712#specification-of-the-eth_signtypeddata-json-rpc). For example:

```
use SleepFinance\Eip712;
use kornrunner\Secp256k1;



$mailTypedData = [
    "types" => [
        "EIP712Domain" => [
            [
                "name" => "name",
                "type" => "string"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "version",
                "type" => "string"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "chainId",
                "type" => "uint256"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "verifyingContract",
                "type" => "address"
            ]
        ],
        "Person" => [
            [
                "name" => "name",
                "type" => "string"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "wallet",
                "type" => "address"
            ]
        ],
        "Mail" => [
            [
                "name" => "from",
                "type" => "Person"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "to",
                "type" => "Person"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "contents",
                "type" => "string"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "primaryType" => "Mail",
    "domain" => [
        "name" => "Ether Mail",
        "version" => "1",
        "chainId" => 1,
        "verifyingContract" => "0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC"
    ],
    "message" => [
        "from" => [
            "name" => "Cow",
            "wallet" => "0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826"
        ],
        "to" => [
            "name" => "Bob",
            "wallet" => "0xbBbBBBBbbBBBbbbBbbBbbbbBBbBbbbbBbBbbBBbB"
        ],
        "contents" => "Hello, Bob!"
    ]
];
$eip712 = new Eip712($mailTypedData);

$hashToSign = $eip712->hashTypedDataV4();

//signing with account 0xf3022686aa43B98362c989659561b9B348977897
$pvk="0x2870b52bfe2401ac0eed7f62fd4bd03eb579c61369c6b4dd6931fb4a57d71b09";

$secp256k1 = new Secp256k1();

$signed   = $secp256k1->sign($hashToSign, $pvk);

//Hex
$signatureToSubmit = $signed->toHex();
```